# count the number of pictures in ubercart3

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

please help count the number of pictures. I create a node node - product.tpl.php her pictures and printing some goods as follows:

```
<?php
    print render($content['uc_product_image']['0']);
    print render($content['uc_product_image']['1']);
?>
```

you want to count the number of images that are associated with this product.

I have tried

```
echo('<pre>');
print count($content['uc_product_image']);
echo('</pre>');
```

did not help(

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in custom modules to get the count

`$count = count($node->uc_product_image['und']);`